# Why does bologna inflate radially when on stove?

Tags: thermodynamics, convection, heat-conduction, food

I noticed that when heating up bologna in any way it inflates at the center, while other stuff tends to let the air escape sideways, or inflates in different places, like an egg or sausage. Nothing so far I have seen, just inflates radially (as if all air heater prefers going towards the center rather than escaping sideways, or generating several convection points like sausages).

How would you explain this event?

Comment: I know this is not Seasoned Advices SE, but what is Bologna there and if it is mortadella why do you warm it up?

Comment: Mortadella is derived from bologna. But they are around the same I suppose. I normally enjoy that hot, like a hot dog winner, rather than cold, personally.

Comment: Well, at least the category is the about the same of a Wiener. About inflation, it could be a complex problem. But is rather intuitive to me. Besides sacks and grains of different composition, more spherical you go more easily get radial symmetry. And mortadella is quite compact, opposite to luganega or an egg.